# Use of "bash" or "zsh" depending on OS and installation

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

I have a small function which executes a command line tool like 7za. I don't know where this tool is installed by the user, so I use this function:

```
func execute(commandName: String, arguments: [String]) -> String? {
        guard var bashCommand = execute(command: "/bin/bash" , arguments: ["-l", "-c", "which \(commandName)"]) else { return "\(commandName) not found" }   // find path of command itself, e.g. "/usr/local/bin/7za"
        bashCommand = bashCommand.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)   // remove newline character at the end
        if bashCommand == "" { return nil }  // command not even found! => nil
        return execute(command: bashCommand, arguments: arguments)   // now we have: /usr/local/bin/7za e -pPW -o/Users/Shared/File.JPG.7z
    }
```

On OSX 10.15 there is a new shell zsh. I can switch my command from bash to zsh, but my program should run on any system. How can I find out which command to use? I don't want to scan the entire harddisk to simply run an installed command line tool lile "7za". Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the shell you use matters? It's not clear you even *want* to involve a shell. `execute(command: "which", arguments: [commandName])`.

Comment: I tried it. This call doesn't return (in time)!?

Comment: Slightly tangential, but you should use `command -v`, not `which` to find the path: https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/3561275

Comment: Thanks omajid, I put this also in mind and replaced "which" by "command -v".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I find out which (shell) command to use?

Ideas:

1. Use `System.getenv("SHELL")` to find out the shell that the user is using, and use that.
2. Use `/bin/sh`.  It should be a link to a POSIX compatible shell; either `bash` or `ksh` ... or possibly something else.
3. Run `ls -l /bin/` and parse the output looking for commands that match `*sh`.
4. Read the `/etc/shells` file.

(See [How can I check the available shells in Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421026/how-can-i-check-the-available-shells-in-mac-osx))

Apple have not (yet) said that `bash` is going away.  At this stage all they have changed is what the *default* shell is.

---

But I'm not convinced it is necessary to do this in the first place:

- You don't need to use a shell to run `which`.  It should be available as an ordinary (not shell built-in) command.  (It is on Linux ...)
- You should not need to use `which 7za`.  What that does is to find the `7za` command using the PATH variable.  But that exactly the same command that will be found and executed if you simply run `7za`.
- If the user installs `7za` and puts it in a strange place that is not on the PATH, they are being perverse.  They need to update their PATH setting, or put the command in a more conventional place.

Comment: Putting the last two points in another way, simply document that your program requires the use of `7za`, and it is the user's responsibility to ensure their `PATH` is set correct to allow `execute(command: '7za', ...)` to find it.

Comment: Thanks for so many ideas! I used 2. "/bin/sh" which seems to be the quickest and easiest solution to handle the two shells.